One Click Unsubscribe For Yahoo Not Working
We have implemented a one-click unsubscribe option for our emails.
We can see the unsubscribe link in both Yahoo and Gmail. However, when a Yahoo user clicks the link, we are not receiving the POST response. It works correctly for Gmail.
Excepting a post request to the server once the user clicks on the unsubscribe in the YAHOO

Have you found any solution ? I am also facing the same issue
